# Positrons in space, are they remnants of baryon asymmetry?

Tags: cosmology, antimatter, baryogenesis

This [recent paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41550-019-0733-z)

> By observing 1.9 million positrons (out of 107 billion cosmic rays), the AMS Collaboration finds that the energy dependence of the positron flux is very complex.

...

> Overall, the flux fits a profile with two peaks: a low-energy diffuse term corresponding to positrons from cosmic ray and ISM collisions and a high-energy source term corresponding to dark matter annihilation or astrophysical acceleration.

If one supposes that equal particles and antiparticles exist before baryon formation, there would be as many positrons in excess as the  number of hydrogen atoms due to the still unknown baryon asymmetry mechanism. So there should be similar to the cosmic microwave background a positron signal, ofcourse due to charge with different characteristics. What induces baryon asymmetry is an open question, but certainly positrons will not be affected as they are mainly electromagnetic interactions, so there should be an excess in intergalactic space.

My question is: does anybody know of a paper that includes the behavior of positrons at the same  time of baryon asymmetry generation?

Comment: Does the paper explain "dark matter annihilation or astrophysical acceleration" to those new to the subject. Am I allowed to ask: can even protons be created in vacuum that way?

Comment: @PeterBernhard the paper is about the observation, the question is about whether there exists a paper with a theory that could fit/explain the observations., and as the question got no answers the answer to your question is also unknown.

Comment: My understanding is that there have not been empirically seen any protons appearing in space; I think the issue relates to Casimir phenomenon. Ref. to "astrophysical acceleration" - would photons nearing some black hole accelerated in that sense? (This is my "last comment", because of policy here).

Comment: @PeterBernhard here is a paper discussing cosmic electrons and protons https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.02375  see the observations https://home.cern/science/physics/cosmic-rays-particles-outer-space

Comment: This https://ams02.space/physics/towards-understanding-origin-cosmic-ray-electrons has interesting figures

Comment: Last link seems broken, just letting you know. Thank you for all advice you give!